How to preload css file in next js 14
When loading a page, the file that blocks rendering is the stylesheet.
Tailwindcss is used in the project, when building next it creates a file that is stored at _next/static/css/generated file name. When you go to the site in Dom there is a link tag with information about this style file, how can I make it so that there is also a link tag with rel='preload'?
Or maybe there are other options to solve this problem, please tell me
gpt advised to try import "../styles/globals.css?precedence=high" but it didn't help)
